# how use HttpWebRequest for POST method in c# without occure timeout exception

Tags: c#, winforms, timeoutexception

I want to run some POST method Continuous. Means:

```
POST 1

POST 2

POST 3

.

.

.
```

Some of this POST data may be get timeout error.

What is best code for implement this to avoid any exception ? Every Post method run after Previous POST method.

Given that these requests may be interrupted, what is the best way to implement them?

my code is :

```
string url = "http://...../login.cgi";
            HttpWebRequest http = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
            CookieContainer cookieJar = new CookieContainer();
            http.CookieContainer = cookieJar;
            http.KeepAlive = false;
            http.Timeout = 4000;
            http.ServicePoint.ConnectionLeaseTimeout = 4000;
            http.ServicePoint.MaxIdleTime = 4000;
            http.Method = "POST";
            http.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
           string postData = "submit=ipv4"; //example
            byte[] dataBytes = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
            http.ContentLength = dataBytes.Length;
            using (Stream postStream = http.GetRequestStream())
            {
                postStream.Write(dataBytes, 0, dataBytes.Length);
            }
            try
            {
                HttpWebResponse httpResponse = http.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
            }
            catch (Exception) { return false; }
            Task.Delay(3500).Wait();
////////////
 HttpWebRequest http2 = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            http2.CookieContainer = cookieJar;
            http2.KeepAlive = false;
            http2.Timeout = 4000;
            http2.ServicePoint.ConnectionLeaseTimeout = 4000;
            http2.ServicePoint.MaxIdleTime = 4000;
            http2.Method = "POST";
            http2.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            postData ="some Data";
            dataBytes = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
            http2.ContentLength = dataBytes.Length;
            using (Stream postStream = http2.GetRequestStream())
            {
                postStream.Write(dataBytes, 0, dataBytes.Length);
            }
            try
            {
                HttpWebResponse httpResponse = http2.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
            }
            catch (Exception) { return false; }
            Task.Delay(3500).Wait();
.
.
.
.
.
.
```

i get some time timeout exception on this line :

```
            using (Stream postStream = http.GetRequestStream())
```

I want to sure every POST request will complete before run next post request

Comment: @Julien tnx if u can help me

Comment: DId you read the [remark](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httpwebrequest?view=net-7.0#remarks): **"We don't recommend that you use HttpWebRequest for new development. Instead, use the System.Net.Http.HttpClient class."** ?

Comment: Also, do not use `.Wait()`. Go async all the way or don't at all.

Comment: @Fildor tnx. can u correct my code?  i am newbie.

Comment: I was going to suggest why go async at all if you want to guarantee that it runs synchronously?

Comment: @Joe_DM i am newbie. plz help to correct my code.

Comment: _"What is best code for implement this to avoid any exception ?"_ - That's futile. Exceptions _will_ happen in the context of network code. The point is: They can be handled more or less cleverly. So if you want to _handle_ for example timeouts, you'd probably go for a resiliency solution like Polly. Which goes along HttpClient very smoothly. But it's too much to cram into an answer here. YT is full of tutorials about this, though.

Comment: Use HttpClient instead of HttpWebRequest. Create an async Task / Task<T> method that issues a Web Request using a provided URI. Make a List of these Tasks. Loop the list and await each Task if you want to run one after the other, or use `Task.WhenAll()` to run all Tasks concurrently. HttpClient doesn't necessarily throw if the response StatusCode is > 399, but you can text `IsSuccessStatusCode` to determine whether the request failed (or requires further actions, like following a redirection)

Comment: @Jimi tnx. can u give a complete tourtial link?

Comment: Start from here: [Guidelines for using HttpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/networking/http/httpclient-guidelines), disregard everything related to IHttpClientFactory for now, but consider setting a `PooledConnectionLifetime` value, depending on how many requests you create. Then: [Make HTTP requests with the HttpClient class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/networking/http/httpclient)

Comment: Read the introduction in: [Use IHttpClientFactory to implement resilient HTTP requests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests), with specific focus on how you should (must) declare a HttpClient object